# Surveys which capture income of individuals and other details

Tags: data-request

Please provide list of surveys which capture income of individuals, income determinants like education, age, work experience, field of work etc and, details about his family particularly number of elder brothers. Geography of Interest is US, Europe, Japan and Australia. Time period of interest is post 1980.

Answer (score 3):

You can find education, age, field of work (industry or occupation) in any National Labor Survey.

If you are particularly interested in family composition of individuals, you could be interested by the Panel Study of Income Dynamics (PSID) made by the University of Michigan for the US. If I remember well, the same families are interviewed on a regular basis and the survey keeps track of family composition and extension. You can know for instance when a member of the family (a son for instance) leaves the household to form a new household, and you can have access to personal and labor market characteristics of any member of the household.